# How to run VB code on an online platform

Tags: vb.net, vba, azure

I am currently developing a system that employs various different code facets. We have a back-end piece of working code written in VB that we need to send to a live platform such as Azure. This will need to be accessed as a function that can return a series of base level values to a piece of front-end code that can display those values in an app and web platform.

The code we are trying to host looks like this (this is just a tiny excerpt of a very large piece of code):

```
Sub InitialiseCalendarArray()

    'This initialises the names of the 4 sessions and the cleans out and initialises the student calendar array

    'NOTE - The InitialiseWeekInfoArray routine must be called before this routine otherwise some of the data will not be available

    Dim cnDb As OleDbConnection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim TransferOLECommand As OleDbCommand
    Dim DbReader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim intWeek As Integer
    Dim intWeekDay As Integer
    Dim intDay As Integer
    Dim intSession As Integer

    garr_strSessionNames(1) = "Morning"
    garr_strSessionNames(2) = "Midday"
    garr_strSessionNames(3) = "Afternoon"
    garr_strSessionNames(4) = "Evening"

    For intWeek = 1 To gc_intNumWeeks
        For intWeekDay = 1 To 7
            intDay = (intWeek - 1) * 7 + intWeekDay
            For intSession = 1 To 4
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_intWeek = intWeek
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_blnWeekday = f_blnIsWeekday(intDay)
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_blnPaper = False
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_blnStudy = False
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_blnSplitSession = False
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_blnExam = False
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_blnFilled = False
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_blnFixed = False
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_strDisplayText = ""
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_intSubjectNumber = 0
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_intNumEveningSessionsLeft = 0
                garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_intNumStudySessionBlocksLeft = 0
                If f_blnIsWeekday(intDay) Then
                    garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_intMaxStudySessionBlocks = garr_udtWeekInfo(intWeek).g_intNumStudySessionBlocksWeekday
                Else
                    garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, intSession).g_intMaxStudySessionBlocks = garr_udtWeekInfo(intWeek).g_intNumStudySessionBlocksWeekend
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

    cnDb = Nothing
    Call f_blnOpenDBConnection(cnDb, True, True)

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM NumEveningSessions ORDER BY WeekNumber"

    'Run the command
    TransferOLECommand = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cnDb)

    'Send the CommandText to the connection, and then build an OleDbDataReader forward-only.
    DbReader = TransferOLECommand.ExecuteReader()
    Do While (DbReader.Read())
        For intDay = DbReader("WeekNumber") * 7 - 6 To DbReader("WeekNumber") * 7
            garr_udtStudentCalendarDay(intDay, 4).g_intNumEveningSessionsLeft = f_intGetProjectedValue(DbReader("MinNumberEveningSessionBlocks"), DbReader("MaxNumberEveningSessionBlocks"), g_intEffort)   'number of evening sessions for this week and level
        Next
    Loop

    DbReader.Close()
    Call CloseDBConnection(cnDb)

End Sub
```

Our system needs a database to draw information from and manipulates that information using a long series of complicated functions.

What sort of conversion are we going to need to do and how we would go about hosting this as a function, would a virtual machine on Azure be the simplest way?

Comment: is it `VB.NET` or is it `VBA` ??? please delete one of the tags.

Comment: ASP.NET Web API? You can deploy it right to Azure from VS - https://www.asp.net/web-api